# How to make firefox Web Developer Panel for css back to the right panel ?

Tags: firefox, visual-web-developer

This Feature by default was removed in firefox (problably firefox 20).
The new design is realy not accessible enought for my 14" laptop.

How can i bring it back ? 
Alternatively, maybe i can downgrade my Firefox to version 19, but i think it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) set the value of `devtools.toolbox.host` to **side**.

[about:config Entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)

Comment: Nope, not what i want. I want only the css tools to stick on the right panel, while other tools stick on the botom, not all the web developer toolbox to stick on the right panels.